# How can I check if scrips on my site are making any requests?

Tags: javascript, request, xmlhttprequest

I mean I know I can check it in chrome dev tools for example but I would like to know how can I do it without browser.

Comment: What do you mean by "without a browser"? That's equivalent to the halting problem.

Comment: Why are there scripts on your site if you don't know what they do? Are they from an advertising network or something like that?

Comment: @Pointy yea lets say its something like commercial scripts.

Comment: @SLaks I simply don't want to use browser or program like wireshark for this. I prefer something on server side. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: There's no general way to do it. If you get scripts from third parties, you should contact them to find out what they do. And if you don't trust them to answer honestly, you shouldn't be using their scripts in the first place.

Comment: BTW how is chrome able to catch all requests? I did some research by measuring all css/images requests and it seems that chrome did calculate all additional JS requests properly. There will no complicated scripts I guess only some basic google analytics/maps/tracking scripts so maybe there is some king of chrome extension to pass request data to my server?

Comment: https://varvy.com/tools/requests/ --- https://www.giftofspeed.com/request-checker/ --- they ale give different results... most accurate is chrome browser but hell I don't know HOW it measure request on js page files.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to check from your operating system. You can install one of the apps below to check the network requests from your computer.
[fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
[wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

[See this answer for more info.](https://superuser.com/questions/357123/how-can-i-monitor-all-the-outgoing-http-requests-from-my-pc)

Comment: yea programs like wireshark is an nice option. But I need something on a server side - apache, node etc. I would like to check how many request from js scripts a page is doing.

Comment: @termitek12 well from *your* server all you can tell are the requests being made to it. You can't tell if the scripts are making requests to other URLs.

Comment: @Pointy no, site is NOT on MY server. I would like to analyze it (this page) js requests. The thing is I can download page content, but how to analyze it from point of made requests, I have no idea.

Comment: @termitek12 well the client browsers are not going to tell your server about random HTTP requests they make. The scripts might fetch images or other scripts from any other URL on the internet, and your server won't know. Browsers don't provide APIs that could tell your own JavaScript about what other code is doing.

Comment: Hmmm I'm thinking... if I'm able to download page content and execute it on MY server will server able to catch all requests? Is there any browser emulator on server side?

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome devtools records network requests by hooking into the Chrome implementation.

You're looking for Chrome's new headless mode, which will run Chrome on a server with no UI and let you control and monitor it directly.

Comment: Thanks! I will do more research in that direction.